# Optaplanner : At least one employee of each type

Tags: optimization, optaplanner

I am solving a problem similar to employee rostering. I have an additional constraint. The employees have a "type" value assigned to them. It's a hard constraint that atleast 1 employee of each "type" be there everyday. How can I model this?

I cannot use the fairness constraint as I don't want to enforce equal number of employees of each "type". Just that atleast 1 of each "type" is present.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not`:

```
when
   Employee()
   Day()
   not Shift(that employee, that day)
then
   -1hard
end
```

Comment: Can you explain this little more? I didn't get how to use this to ensure all the types are covered.

Comment: Ok, I got what you mean here.
Only issue is, I have not defined `Day` as an object. It is used just as date string. How can I initialize that?

Comment: Also, my employee types are defined in an enum. How can I write the rule for all EmployeeType ? Is there a way to iterate over EmployeeType.values() and repeat the rule for all of them?